# How to remove the blue bar showing weather information on Samsung Tab 4 T231?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-tab-4

For weather information, time, and unread messages information there is a blue bar on the home screen.

I don't want that. What is the way to remove it?

Comment: Could you post the screenshot of your home screen having the blue bar? What changes do you observe on your home screen if you tap and hold that bar?

Comment: If its on the homescreen you could try to long press on it and drag it to the X or garbage can. That should remove it from your home screen.

Comment: @jer3my that was it. Please post that as an answer. I could see the garbage can on tapping and holding the blue bar and I din't know how to use it.

Comment: @Firelord Thanks, I tried again and saw the garbage can as usual, but I didn't know how to use that as of now.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius Glad it worked for you. =)

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius that is called a widget and your were using a weather widget on your homescreen. You can press and hold to add widgets to your homescreen. And drag them to the top of the screen to remove it More on [Widgets](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5988/what-is-a-widget)

Comment: @Lucky the blue also contained time, and unread messages info. Why would that be called a weather widget?

Comment: It really makes me wonder...

Comment: Widgets come as system default and also by 3rd party apps you install. You may have installed some apps which would have added this to your homescreen. and Could you post the screenshot of the homescreen.? Press and hold Power and Volume down keys together to take screenshots.

Comment: I assume the widget he is talking about is the default "All in one" one that samsung puts on damn near everything they make. Top half of this screen.

https://cdn.recombu.com/mobile/images/phones/1328/1394122627.png

It will show unchecked texts and etc in there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its on the homescreen you could try to long press on it and drag it to the X or garbage can. That should remove it from your home screen.